# Vim - QuickTex is incompatible with Auto-Pairs or Auto-Close

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-auto-pairs

I'm looking to set up Vim for Latex editing and I came across this very simple and useful plugin,
[QuickTex](https://github.com/brennier/quicktex). However, I doesn't seem to be compatible with [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) nor with [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) (which are plugins that automatically close matching brackets among other stuff). This has also been addressed by QuickTex's developer (see [here](https://github.com/brennier/quicktex/issues/9)), but no solution was found. This dates back to a year or two ago. Has anyone looked into it since? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As it stands, I think this question is probably a bit too vague and/or open-ended to elicit good answers. If you added a few more details about specifically what goes wrong when you try to use QuickTex, then you're probably a bit more likely to get helpful suggestions.

Comment: @Rich You're right, but I have no idea where to start. When both plugins are installed, characters such as brackets and quotes do automatically close but the keywords listed in QuickTex's dictionaries do not expand as they're supposed to. For instance, typing ```<Enter><Enter>``` in insert mode should look for the ```<++>``` pattern and jump to the first match, yet it simply inserts two blank spaces. As far I can tell, no keyword expands.

Comment: Just found out that delimitMate seems to work.

Comment: The info in your comment is a great example of being more specific. You should edit it into the question itself!